# How to display the hidden div after page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement that when click on a button the page need to reload.after reload i need to show the hidden div.

below is my requirement which describe my problem?

1.In my html code consist of some text along with button and in this page only by default i am hiding some text div
2.when click on the button i am reloading the page .after reload the page i want show hidden div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#test2").css("visibility","hidden");
        alert("reloaded");

        $("#p1").click(function(){

          setTimeout(function(e){
            alert("inside time out");
            $("#p2").css("visibility","visible");
          },3000);
          location.reload();

        });    
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="myDiv">
      <p id="p1">This is sample text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="test2">

      <p id="p2">this is invisible text</p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd start by adding a button to your code since your requirement is that the page reloads after the click of a button.

Comment: you can use cookie, or hash, web storage

Comment: Suresh, why haven't you accepted an answer to any of your questions?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `localStorage` item when a user clicks the button, and on page load look for the `localStorage` item and conditionally show the hidden div.

```js
var $hidden = $('.hidden');

localStorage.getItem('show') && $hidden.show();

$('button').on('click',function() {
  localStorage.setItem('show',true);
  window.location.reload(false); 
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">hidden</div>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if your requirement is to have a button be clicked, you'll need a button, not a paragraph.

Next, instead of the `visibility` property (which still allocates space on the page for the element even when it is not shown), use `display` (which does not).

Most importantly, if you reload the document, then any local variables you have will be lost. You need to persist some kind of "flag" between page loads. This can be done in a variety of ways (cookies, sessionStorage, localStorage, server-side), but **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** is probably the simplest.

This code won't actually run, here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment due to sandboxing, but you can see a working version of it **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrb70kxh/7/)**.

See other comments inline:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        // Check to see if this is a page reload or not by seeing if a value was placed
        // into localStorage from a previous page load
        if(localStorage.getItem("loadedEarlier")){
          // Page has already loaded earlier
          $("#test2").css("display","block");
        }
        
        $("#btn").click(function(){
          location.reload();
        });    
        
        // Place a value into localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("loadedEarlier", "yes")        
});
```

```css
/* No need for JavaScript to initially hide the element which
   can cause the usre to see it momentarially before the JS runs.
   Set its default display to none instead.                      */
#test2 { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click to Reload</button>
<div id="test2"><p id="p2">this is invisible text</p></div>
```